# Jackson fails to read java.util.List as generic type

Tags: java, json, jackson

When I try to serialize and deserialize again a List inside a generic type Jackson fails.

There's a JDoodle if you want to play with a working example: https://jdoodle.com/a/6nJ4

This is my generic class

```
public static class UserMessageResult<T> {

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
    private T entity;

    public UserMessageResult() {
    }


    public UserMessageResult(T entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
    }
}
```

And this is the class used as a generic within the list

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.CLASS, include = As.PROPERTY)
public static class AnEntity {

    private int anInt;
    private String aString;

    public AnEntity() {
    }

    public AnEntity(int anInt, String aString) {
        this.anInt = anInt;
        this.aString = aString;
    }

    public int getAnInt() {
        return anInt;
    }

    public String getaString() {
        return aString;
    }

}
```

If I put `AnEntity` inside a `List` and add this list to a `UserMessageResult` Jackson fails to read the JSON it just created.

```
    List<AnEntity> anEntityList= List.of(
        new AnEntity(10, "aaa"),
        new AnEntity(20, "bbb")
    );
    UserMessageResult<List<AnEntity>> userMessageResult = new UserMessageResult(anEntityList);
    System.out.println(userMessageResult);
    
    String jsonStr = MAPPER.writeValueAsString(userMessageResult);
    System.out.println(jsonStr);
    

    final TypeReference<UserMessageResult<List<AnEntity>>> typeRef = new TypeReference<>() {
    };

    UserMessageResult<List<AnEntity>> actualUserMessageResult = MAPPER.readValue(jsonStr, typeRef);
    System.out.println(actualUserMessageResult);
```

Error Message

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve subtype of [simple type, class MyClass$AnEntity]: missing type id property '@class' (for POJO property 'entity')
 at [Source: (String)"{
  "entity" : [ "java.util.ImmutableCollections$List12", [ {
    "anInt" : 10,
    "aString" : "aaa"
  }, {
    "anInt" : 20,
    "aString" : "bbb"
  } ] ]
}"; line: 2, column: 16] (through reference chain: MyClass$UserMessageResult["entity"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException.from(InvalidTypeIdException.java:43)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.missingTypeIdException(DeserializationContext.java:2094)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingTypeId(DeserializationContext.java:1607)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._handleMissingTypeId(TypeDeserializerBase.java:307)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedUsingDefaultImpl(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:211)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:122)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeWithType(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1296)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer._deserializeFromArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:361)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:28)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:138)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:314)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:177)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4825)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3772)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3755)
    at MyClass.listOfEntities(MyClass.java:57)
    at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:21)
```

Obviously the @class properties in the list items are missing. If I change the JSON by hand and add the @class properties everything works fine:

```
    System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++ Manualy corrected JSON +++++++++++++++++");
    String jsonStr = """
        {
          "entity" :  [ {
            "@class" : "MyClass$AnEntity",
            "anInt" : 10,
            "aString" : "String 1"
          }, {
            "@class" : "MyClass$AnEntity",
            "anInt" : 20,
            "aString" : "String 2"
          } ] 
        }
        """;

    final TypeReference<UserMessageResult<List<AnEntity>>> typeRef = new TypeReference<>() {
    };

    UserMessageResult<?> actualUserMessageResult = MAPPER.readValue(jsonStr, typeRef);
    System.out.println( actualUserMessageResult);
```

I'm using Jackson 2.15. This has been working correctly in Jackson up to version 2.14.
Playing around with and without the @JsonTypeInfo annotations did not change anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. As you by using `TypeReference` tell the deserializer the type of your object, just remove both the `@JsonTypeInfo` annotations and your `listOfEntities()` code (where you serialize it first and then deserialize the result json String) will start working.
2. If you want to keep the type information stored in the serialized string, instead of `TypeReference` use just a raw type:

```java
MAPPER.readValue(jsonStr, UserMessageResult.class)
```

I checked both the alternatives in my compiler and both work.

Surprisingly, your "manually corrected" `deserializeJson()` method in your jdoodle code does *not* work for me. Here I get an error:

```text
Unrecognized field "aString" (class MyClass$AnEntity)
```

Tested under Spring Boot 3.1.1 with jackson dependency managed by Spring Boot parent:

```xml
<jackson-bom.version>2.15.2</jackson-bom.version>
```

Comment: Are you testing with Jackson 2.15?

Comment: @BetaRide Btw, check also which Jackson version you *actually* use. If you're running under Spring Boot, it handles the versions on its own and it's not recommendable meddling with it. Also some of your other libraries might bring you an unwanted transitive dependency.